# Laravel and phpword possibilities

Tags: php, laravel, phpword

I use laravel but I think this question is more about php word.

Is it possible with this package to export word with custom text at some points ?

For example, my word template contain three locations to change. So with phpword can I export this template with custom text at this three locations ?

Can I change only part of text or must I change all paragraph ?

Thank for you informations.

Comment: I am fairly sure the answer will be YES. I am just not totally sure what the question is

Comment: Can I change text "blabla" on page 1, text "blobloblo" on page 10 and text "bliblibli"  inside a paragraph on page 30 ?

Comment: Well as the document can be built completely using phpword, you can do whatever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setValue()` method to replace the text.

Depending on which version you are using, version 0.12.0 and up use
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor

```
public function setValue($search, $replace, $limit = self::MAXIMUM_REPLACEMENTS_DEFAULT)
{
    if (is_array($search)) {
        foreach ($search as &$item) {
            $item = self::ensureMacroCompleted($item);
        }
    } else {
        $search = self::ensureMacroCompleted($search);
    }
    if (is_array($replace)) {
        foreach ($replace as &$item) {
            $item = self::ensureUtf8Encoded($item);
        }
    } else {
        $replace = self::ensureUtf8Encoded($replace);
    }
    if (Settings::isOutputEscapingEnabled()) {
        $xmlEscaper = new Xml();
        $replace = $xmlEscaper->escape($replace);
    }
    $this->tempDocumentHeaders = $this->setValueForPart($search, $replace, $this->tempDocumentHeaders, $limit);
    $this->tempDocumentMainPart = $this->setValueForPart($search, $replace, $this->tempDocumentMainPart, $limit);
    $this->tempDocumentFooters = $this->setValueForPart($search, $replace, $this->tempDocumentFooters, $limit);
}
```

Link to method -> https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/src/PhpWord/TemplateProcessor.php#L208

Before version 0.12.0 use \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Template

```
public function setValue($search, $replace, $limit = -1)
{
    foreach ($this->headerXMLs as $index => $headerXML) {
        $this->headerXMLs[$index] = $this->setValueForPart($this->headerXMLs[$index], $search, $replace, $limit);
    }
    $this->documentXML = $this->setValueForPart($this->documentXML, $search, $replace, $limit);
    foreach ($this->footerXMLs as $index => $headerXML) {
        $this->footerXMLs[$index] = $this->setValueForPart($this->footerXMLs[$index], $search, $replace, $limit);
    }
}
```

Link to method -> https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/e35838f7d7928b2308df3f7f0ef6d49bf96f453c/src/PhpWord/Template.php#L131

Comment: What must I searched ? Sorry I'm new to php word and I don't fully understand how to change the right part of my document.

Comment: The `setValue` method is preset in PHPword, so you just need to use them. An example would be `$phpWordObj->setValue('hello', 'goodbye');` where `$phpWordObj` is the PHPWord object. This would search for the string `hello` and replace it with `goodbye`

Comment: I tried to load word first but I've an unkown error when I try to open it :         $templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('resources/Sample_23_TemplateBlock.docx');
        $templateProcessor->saveAs('resources/Sample_24_TemplateBlock.docx');
        return response()->download(public_path('resources/Sample_24_TemplateBlock.docx'));